# How do I get the fan page id with the user id in the Facebook graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Graph API I need a way to get the fan page id using that page created "user id".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the ID of the user who created the page? The "creator" of the page may no longer be an admin of the page, or even have an account on Facebook. What you should be looking for is the IDs of the users who are admins of the page, there can be more than one.

Comment: thanks for answering,
I know the one admin id of the page(creator of the page) ,then is it passible to get page id

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing https://graph.facebook.com/USER/accounts?access_token=...

Answer (score 0):

Just load https://graph.facebook.com/yourpagename and change "yourpagename" to what your username is. it'll output all the info and your id will be in there